# Получаю ошибку 500 Internal Server Error в ajax, django POST форме

Tags: python, django, ajax

Я делаю форму для добавления почт пользователей в базу данных чтобы в дальнейшем делать рассылку по ним.

Я использую AJAX в форме чтобы страница не обновлялась при submit'е

Вот мой html код:

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
   <form action="" method="post" id = "malistform">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="email" id = "mailist" name = "mailist" required placeholder = "Впишите свою почту">
      <input type = "submit" value = "Подписатсья">
   </form>
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
  $(document).on("submit", "#malistform", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:'{% url 'core:mailist' %}',
      data:{
        mail:$('#mailist').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
      },
      success: function(){

      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Мой `views.py`, отвечающий за сохранение почты в БД:

```py
def mailist(request):
    response_data = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        mail = request.POST.get('mailist')
        response_data['mail'] = mail
        f = Email(mail = mail)
        f.save()
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

`urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name = "index"),
    path("blog", views.blog, name = "blog"),
    path('email', views.email, name = 'email'),
    path("blog-single", views.blogSingle, name = "blogSingle"),
    path("portfolio-details", views.portfolioDetails, name = "portfolioDetails"),
    path('add-form', views.addForm, name = "form"),
    path('success', views.success, name = 'success'),
    path('mailist', views.mailist, name = 'mailist')
]
```

Модель почты `models.py`:

```py
class Email(models.Model):
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mail
```

ошибка с `терминала`:

> ```
>   return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: core_email.mail
> ```